# Monitor logs managed by Wazuh and OSSEC

Tags: hids, ossec, hid-analysis

Today I use OSSEC as HIDS, but reading Wazuh's site it seems to be more modern and has more resources.

I saw that it has an Elastic Stack integration, something I don't interested about due to using Java and using a lot of server resources.

Does Wazuh have a way that I can export its detection to some environment like Zabbix, another or even visualize it in a private cloud?

Or if I keep using OSSEC, does it have any feature to monitor the logs without me having to email these detections?

Answer (score 1):

Starting Wazuh 4.3.x, Wazuh includes the Wazuh indexer and the Wazuh dashboard, based on OpenSearch, among many other improvements, check this blog to learn more: [Introducing Wazuh 4.3.0](https://wazuh.com/blog/introducing-wazuh-4-3-0)

You could easily install Wazuh in just a few minutes using the [Wazuh installation assistant](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/quickstart.html), or give it a try by downloading the ready-to-use virtual machine [OVA](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deployment-options/virtual-machine/virtual-machine.html) or the pre-built Amazon Machine Image [AMI](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/deployment-options/amazon-machine-images/amazon-machine-images.html).

Regarding the resources consumption, the recommended hardware resources to monitor up to 25 agents are 4vCPU, 8 GiB of RAM and 50 GB of storage to keep the alerts for 90 days. Check the Wazuh quickstart [hardware requirements](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/quickstart.html#hardware) to learn more.

As an alternative, you could install only the Wazuh manager without the indexer and dashboard components and forward the logs in the `/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json` file to an external tool.